# Matlab index in range yet I get out of range

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to  extract the model parameters using:

```
clc
clear all
data = xlsread('cancer_train.xlsx');
X = data(:,1:9);
Y = data(:,10);
mdl = fitcnb(X,Y);
mu=[];
[m,n] = size(data);
for i = 1:m
    mu(i,1) = mdl.DistributionParameters{1,i}(1);
end
```

I get index out of range after element 9! The excel can be found here: http://dropcanvas.com/#S47z19vg5WISRQ

Answer (score 0):

Your X is taken from the data, all rows and columns from 1 to 9. Into X there is no column 10. I think you have to modify your for loop as it follows

```
for i = 1:m
    mu(i,1) = mdl.DistributionParameters{i,1}(i);
end
```

because m is the number of rows, so index i has to be used in rows, not columns. In your code, you were reading always row 1, and the loop was on columns of X.

If you want to read columns, n should be used

```
for i = 1:n
    mu(1,i) = mdl.DistributionParameters{1,i}(1);
end
```